# JavaScript library like JsonViewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

I am trying to write the documentation of a custom HTTP API. I would like to see it like a demo client, with real responses. 
In design there will be 3 columns, 1 for request methods, 1 for JsonViewer and 1 for html output.

My question is if there a library (JS) to help me in the JsonViewer like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this JQuery library. 
https://github.com/quickredfox/jquery-jsonview .
It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple JSON viewer. It parses JSON from string by standard JSON.parse() method, and draws json-tree.
You can use only jsonTree library from editor in your project and create many json-trees on one html page.

[jsonTree](https://github.com/summerstyle/jsonTreeViewer) library (part of jsonTreeViewer)